Setting up jenkins on multiuserlogin systems
I am tasked with setting up the jenkins master and slave. I have a linux machine which I intend to make the master and several other machines(both linux and windows) that are to be set as child nodes.
The problem at hand is that all these machines are multi-user-login systems, and it requires me to login in order to perform any kind of actions/steps in setting up. Right now the master is created with my username. I set up the jenkins child node similarly by logging using my credentials. Unfortunately on the web GUI, it always shows up as the child node is offline.
Is it advisable to create generic usernames and create the master and node using those IDs. If so, can you briefly explain the points associated with it
PS: These nodes will be used by other users in my team as well.
Set up the jenkins master and slave using my credentials.

It doesn't matter who installs Jenkins on a system.  Generally you want to setup server programs like Jenkins (doesn't matter if it's master or a slave node) to run in the system context ( IE, as a service), as a local system user that's not you, and has the lowest privileges possible.  I usually just create a local system account named Jenkins with minimal privileges.
The slave nodes are easy to setup but not totally straight forward.  At a high level, each requires a unique key generated by the Jenkins master under Manage Jenkins -> Nodes, and the master has to be setup with the proper configuration settings to allow slaves to connect under Manage Jenkins -> Security -> Agents.  Sorry I can't be more help on the slaves, it's been a long time since I set one up.
